# tkinter display values in a popup

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to make some basic GUI and I'm having some trouble with this code:

```
with open(project_dir + 'logs/wash.log') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        if not line.startswith('BSSID       ') and \
           not line.startswith('------------'):
            print(line)
```

At this point of the application I have the tkinter root already opened in the background and a terminal opened too, I would like to open a new tkinter window in which display the line printed above, I suppose adding a label in the window for each line that I need to display.

I tried tk.Toplevel() but I don't know how to make the new window in which display the strings.

My problem is I am trying to create a new window and print the strings there, I have tried tk.Toplevel() but I don't know how to make the new window in which to display the strings

Comment: if you want to display large amounts of text look into the `Text` widget, or the `scrolledtext` widget, rather than a large number of labels.

Comment: Thanks for your help James, my problem is to create a new window and print there the strings, I tried tk.Toplevel() but I don't know how to make the new window in which display the strings

Comment: The simple answer is to place a Text box on your GUI and then write the date to the Text box using the `insert()` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comment:

> my problem is to create a new window and print there the strings, I tried tk.Toplevel() but I don't know how to make the new window in which display the strings

This is a simple example but should help.

I have a button on the root window that links to a function called `new_window()`. This function will create a top level window containing a text box widget. We then use the `with open` statement to write the data to the text box.

```
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()

def new_window():
    top = tk.Toplevel(root)
    my_text_box = tk.Text(top)
    my_text_box.pack()
    with open(project_dir + 'logs/wash.log') as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            if not line.startswith('BSSID       ') and \
               not line.startswith('------------'):
                my_text_box.insert("end", line)

open_new_window = tk.Button(root, text="Open Toplevel", command=new_window)
open_new_window.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Mike, you got exactly what I mean despite my bad question and my english even worse, thank you very much. I'm trying the code right now

Comment: @S.Pnt glad to help. Let me know if it works out for you. If my answer solves your problem don't forget to select the check box next to the answer so everyone can know your issues has been solved.

Comment: I need to fit it in my program and I will select the check box soon, I'm just a little bit busy now, thank you again

Comment: @S.Pnt If this answer is what you are looking for please accept it.

Comment: I solved the problem in another way but I appreciated the help, thanks all guys

Comment: @S.Pnt If you found a better solutions you can write it up here and accept your own answer. It would also server as a reference for anyone who finds this Q/A while searching a similar problem. (Well you could if the question was re-opened.)